# Symfony 3.4 - FOSUserBundle - Overwritting create command failed

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the FOSUser bundle user creation command.

I followed this tutorial: https://blog.overnetcity.com/2012/10/15/symfony2-fosuserbundle-comment-etendre-la-commande-par-defaut-de-creation-dun-utilisateur/

But when I launch my new command, I get this error:

> Cannot autowire service "Site\PagesBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand":
>   argument "**$userManipulator**" of method
>   **"FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand::__construct()"** references
>   class **"FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator"** but no such service
>   exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing
>   **"fos_user.util.user_manipulator"** service.

It seems that no one had this problem before me. Yet I respected the tutorial, the imports, all that was needed.

I show you my code:

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;

class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this
            ->setName('atelech:user:create')
            ->getDefinition()->addArguments(array(
                new InputArgument('nom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Le nom'),
                new InputArgument('prenom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Le prenom')
            ))
        ;
        $this->setHelp(<<<EOT
// L'aide qui va bien
EOT
            );
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $username   = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email      = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password   = $input->getArgument('password');
        $nom        = $input->getArgument('nom');
        $prenom     = $input->getArgument('prenom');
        $inactive   = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        /** @var \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager $user_manager */
        $user_manager = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        /** @var \Acme\AcmeUserBundle\Entity\User $user */
        $user = $user_manager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean) !$inactive);
        $user->setSuperAdmin((Boolean) $superadmin);
        $user->setNom($nom);
        $user->setPrenom($prenom);

        $user_manager->updateUser($user);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        parent::interact($input, $output);
        if (!$input->getArgument('nom')) {
            $nom = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a nom:',
                function($nom) {
                    if (empty($nom)) {
                        throw new \Exception('nom can not be empty');
                    }

                    return $nom;
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('nom', $nom);
        }
        if (!$input->getArgument('prenom')) {
            $prenom = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a prenom:',
                function($prenom) {
                    if (empty($prenom)) {
                        throw new \Exception('prenom can not be empty');
                    }

                    return $prenom;
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('prenom', $prenom);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to add the two attributes "name" and "first name"

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I never used FosUserBundle but the tutorial is really old and related to symfony2 version not 3.4 (big changes between these versions).

Comment: Yeah I know but it was just for a little thing ^^

Answer (score 1):

so..

checked on Symfony 3.4.24 and friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (2.0)

and the code is next according to sources of fosuserbundle:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;

class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this
            ->setName('atelech:user:create')
            ->getDefinition()->addArguments(
                array(
                    new InputArgument('nom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Le nom'),
                    new InputArgument('prenom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Le prenom'),
                )
            );
        $this->setHelp(
            <<<EOT
// L'aide qui va bien
EOT
        );
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $username = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password = $input->getArgument('password');
        $nom = $input->getArgument('nom');
        $prenom = $input->getArgument('prenom');
        $inactive = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        $userManager = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        /** @var \Acme\AcmeUserBundle\Entity\User $user */
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean)!$inactive);
        $user->setSuperAdmin((Boolean)$superadmin);
        $user->setNom($nom);
        $user->setPrenom($prenom);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        parent::interact($input, $output);

        $questions = array();

        foreach (['nom', 'prenom'] as $key) {
            if (!$input->getArgument($key)) {
                $question = new Question("Please choose a $key:");
                $question->setValidator(
                    function ($username) use ($key) {
                        if (empty($username)) {
                            throw new \Exception("$key can not be empty");
                        }

                        return $username;
                    }
                );
                $questions[$key] = $question;
            }
        }

        foreach ($questions as $name => $question) {
            $answer = $this->getHelper('question')->ask($input, $output, $question);
            $input->setArgument($name, $answer);
        }
    }
}
```

and nothing in service.yml - everything is autowired correctly

check for your namespace pls :)

Comment: Now, when I write my command in the CMD, I've this error :   The helper "dialog" is not defined :/ It's because of my symfony version (3.4) I think... And I don't know how can I do my Create command overwritting in this FOSUserBundle version :/ ( sorry for my bad english I'm French)

Comment: well, helper dialog was removed from symfony 3.0 as I remember. try use this one instead - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html

Comment: also can you show your FOSBundle version? why can't you update it?

Comment: I've ths in my composer.json : "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0". Is it good ?
Thanks for your link ! I will read it

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) By cons, if I update the bundle, it will not break everything I've done so far? (overloading of some methods, registration, etc.)?

Comment: hm. I can't guarantee. I'll downgrade my version to 2.0 and check it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191254/discussion-between-myxaxa-and-agar-io-fr).

Answer (score 0):

## Why error

I had this error in symfony 4 but this is issue for all symfony from 3.3 and nevest.

```
In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:

  Cannot autowire service "App\Command\AppUserCreateCommand": argument "$user  
  Manipulator" of method "__construct()" references class "FOS\UserBundle\Uti  
  l\UserManipulator" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this   
  class to the existing "fos_user.util.user_manipulator" service.
```

is because from Symfony 3.3 services are private by default and autowired. To fix you should describe your private argument of constructor of command in `services.yml`.

This code should fix problem:

```
    App\Command\AppUserCreateCommand:
        arguments: ['@fos_user.util.user_manipulator']
```

Second reason of this error. You not overriding constructor, but if constructor of extending class is not declared php uses constructor of parent class. This one:

```
    public function __construct(UserManipulator $userManipulator)
    {
        $this->userManipulator = $userManipulator;
    }
```

so even if you not typed it, `UserManipulator` is used and this is reason of error.

If you want to know more I recommend tutorial: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-3.3/autowiring-aliases

## How I solved this problem?

In my case I resigned from using `FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator` because of his method `create` is too constraint. I create class that extends it:

`src/Util/AppUserManipulator.php`

```
<?php


namespace App\Util;

use App\Entity\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AppUserManipulator extends UserManipulator
{
    /**
     * User manager.
     *
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $dispatcher;

    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * UserManipulator constructor.
     *
     * @param UserManagerInterface     $userManager
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
     * @param RequestStack             $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        parent::__construct($userManager, $dispatcher, $requestStack);
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user and returns it.
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $email
     * @param bool   $active
     * @param bool   $superadmin
     * @param string $firstName
     * @param string $lastName
     * @param string $phoneNumber
     *
     * @return \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
     */
    public function createAppUser($username, $password, $email, $active, $superadmin, $firstName, $lastName, $phoneNumber)
    {
        /**
         * @var User
         */
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        if($user instanceof User) {
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setPlainPassword($password);
            $user->setEnabled((bool)$active);
            $user->setSuperAdmin((bool)$superadmin);
            $user->setFirstName($firstName);
            $user->setLastName($lastName);
            $user->setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

            $event = new UserEvent($user, $this->getRequest());
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::USER_CREATED, $event);

        }
        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return Request
     */
    private function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
}
```

Command that I created has code `src/Command/AppUserCreateCommand.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use App\Util\AppUserManipulator;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class AppUserCreateCommand extends CreateUserCommand
{
    const PROPERTIES = [
        'first_name' => 'First Name',
        'last_name' => 'Last Name',
        'phone_number' => 'Phone Number'
    ];

    protected static $defaultName = 'app:user:create';

    private $userManipulator;

    public function __construct(AppUserManipulator $userManipulator)
    {
        parent::__construct($userManipulator);
        $this->userManipulator = $userManipulator;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setName('app:user:create')
            ->setHelp(preg_replace('/fos:user:create/', 'app:user:create', $this->getHelp()));

        foreach (self::PROPERTIES as $name => $description) {
            $this->addArgument($name, InputArgument::REQUIRED, $description);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // code from parent start
        $username = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password = $input->getArgument('password');
        $inactive = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');
        // code from parent end

        foreach (self::PROPERTIES as $name => $description) {
            ${$name} = $input->getArgument($name);
        }

        $this->userManipulator->createAppUser($username, $password, $email, !$inactive, $superadmin, ...array_keys(self::PROPERTIES));

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        parent::interact($input, $output);

        $questions = array();

        foreach (self::PROPERTIES as $name => $description) {
            if (!$input->getArgument($name)) {
                $question = new Question("Please choose a $name:");
                $question->setValidator(function ($property) use ($name){
                    if (empty($property)) {
                        throw new \Exception("$name can not be empty");
                    }

                    return $property;
                });
                $questions[$name] = $question;
            }
        }

        foreach ($questions as $name => $question) {
            $answer = $this->getHelper('question')->ask($input, $output, $question);
            $input->setArgument($name, $answer);
        }
    }
}
```

to use type

```
./bin/console app:user:create
```

**note**: using my solution you should not change `services.yaml` because of services defined by me like `AppUserManipulator` are autowired by default.